# Generate chm output from doxygen output

Tags: doxygen, chm

I am using

```
chmcmd, a CHM compiler. (c) 2010 Free Pascal core.
```

for generating .chm file from Doxygen output. It presents me with error messages like

```
Warning: Found file dynsections.js while scanning files.html, but couldn't find it on disk
```

and similar for "namespacestd.html". It looks like something has changed in the installation of Doxygen during the times. It is just a warning, but I guess it has reason and consequences. How can I overcome it?

Comment: Which version od doxygen do you use? By head this was an error in an older version of doxygen (specifically seen for LaTeX, but would probably also match the chm generation). In case you are not using the 1.8.14 version I would first try it with the 1.8.14 version, in case the issue persists please create a small example + changes of the standard file in the question or when to large create an issue in the doxygen issue tracker (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

Comment: I use version 1.8.13, so I will upgrade

Comment: Is version 1.8.14 publicly available? My Ubuntu replied sudo apt-get upgrade doxygen
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
doxygen is already the newest version (1.8.13-10).

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.14 is publicly available but some distributions didn't yet generate packages for it. In the later case there are is a thing to do: inform the distribution creator that a newer version is available. Further you can download the source code and generate a doxygen version yourself when of course the proper compilers are present (as generating the package by the distribution might take some time).

Comment: Is the warning correct? If you open files.html do you see the reference to the JS file, and is the js file somewhere in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use ChmCmd but even with Doxygen version 1.8.13 the file `dynsections.js` is always contained in the output directory `..\html` on my Windows10 machine.

Of course I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="dynsections.js"></script>` in `files.html`.

Please first search for the files like `dynsections.js`. Try adding the names of the *.js files to the [FILES] list in your project (.hhp) file. This will ensure that the .js files are compiled into the help file, which may not be the case at present.

If you're using HTML Help Workshop as an alternative to chmcmd, the procedure for adding the file names to the [FILES] section is as follows:

1. Open the .hhp file in HTML Help Workshop.
2. Click the Add/Remove Topic Files button on the Project tab.
3. Click Add.
4. In the File Name field, type *.js.
5. Click Open, select the files to add to the list, and then click Open again.

You can go the short way by editing your *.hhp file with a text editor. Add a new wildcard line for all *.js files in the [FILES] section like:

```
[FILES]
dynsections.js
jquery.js
menu.js
menudata.js
design.css
...
```

Comment: Note some things depend on the settings in the Doxyfile and the project. Without a small project including the exact Doxyfile it is hard to tell.

Comment: I found dynsections.js in my other subdirectory which I did not touch for two years (i.e. it was built under Ubuntu 16.04, I do not know which version of Doxygen. I copied the file and the error gone. Thanks.